# Is it possible to rate limit HTTP requests with iptables?

Tags: nginx, iptables, fail2ban

I've got a lot of vulnerability scans via HTTP requests (trying to get /password.txt, etc). Currently I use fail2ban to parse Nginx access log to count 404's and ban attacker ip addresses. I'm wondering if it possible to simply configure iptables to rate limit HTTP requests instead?

I tried something like this

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2012 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent  --updat…e --seconds 60 --hitcount 5 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
```

but apparently it does not work as expected. My guess is that the malicious HTTP requests are piped through a single persistent connection so the above iptables rule is not triggered.

So my question is: is it possible to rate limit HTTP requests in iptables, or I should stick with fail2ban? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is HTTP 1.1. You'll have to configure your web server to downgrade the connection to 1.0 in order to kill keepalive if you want this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So it confirmed my original suspicion. Unfortunately it is not OK to downgrade to HTTP/1.0. For most users we need to support keep-alive to keep latency down :(